# eloquent search/where on custom attributes

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I added a custom attribute to my model

```
public function getTouchedAttribute() { ...
```

I would like to add this to a query

```
hasMany()->where('touched', ...)
```

but obviously this isn't a column in the table.

what is the most elegant way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One option (and probably the better one in terms of performance) would be to mimic the attribute with raw SQL functions. (Can't help you with that because I don't know what `touched` does)

The other way is to use `filter` on the resulting collection:

```
$collection = Model::all();
$filtered = $collection->filter(function($model){
    return $model->touched == true;
});
```

Comment: Good. This is Good. If it were a simple sql query, then I would have done it that way, but its an amalgamation of several queries and some other variables.

Comment: This will only work for small datasets.  If you are querying a table of 100k records this will be very slow.

Comment: How can you use this with pagination

Comment: This creates a poor performance. When you run `Model::all()` you are trying to read all data from DB and write it on memory. Then you are filtering data from a collection. It's not convenient. If you want to do that keeping performance on mind check my answer which you can handle this need with Local Query Scopes and filter data with DB queries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55076165/1977031

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a 4 year old topic (from 2015) but it's still getting traffic from web searches.
So I want to share an idea;

You can use [Local Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes) of Eloquent to define custom where clauses.

As said in documentation:

> Local scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you
>   may easily re-use throughout your application. For example, you may
>   need to frequently retrieve all users that are considered "popular".
>   To define a scope, prefix an Eloquent model method with scope.

And an example:
If you define a custom scope on your model:

```
public function scopePopular($query)
{
    return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
}
```

You can use it directly with your model.

```
App\User::popular()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

So you can define a `scopeTouched()` method and implement your logic.
I assume if updated_at not equal to created_at the row is touched here. Of course you can change this behaviour.

```
public function scopeTouched($query)
{
    return $query->where('updated_at', '!=', 'created_at');
}
```

And use it with your model.

```
Model::touched()->get();
```

And of course you can use it with other query builder methods.

```
Model::touched()->paginate(20);
Model::touched()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
Model::touched()->latest()->first();
```