# How do I use custom attribute on scope?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

### Using custom attribute on Laravel scope

Model.php

```
public function getClientNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->client->first_name . ' ' . $this->client->last_name;
}


public function scopeSearch($query, $search) 
{
    return $query->where('number', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('client_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
}
```

I'm getting an error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'client_name' in 'where clause'`

Comment: You cannot use these attributes in queries. custom attributes are in php application, not in mysql database

Comment: I also read that you cannot use attributes on queries. Maybe I'll try another solution. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eloquent search/where on custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020053/eloquent-search-where-on-custom-attributes)

Comment: @PouyaHeydari i've come across that solution but no it doesn't answer my problem. But I have solved my problem using `->whereHas('table', function ($query)  {})`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
 ->orWhere('{table_name}.client_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
```

If you are making a join it could help.

Comment: I'm using eloquent relationship tho i tried your suggestion, it doesn't seem to work on my structure :)

I don't know how to use the attribute I created on scope or in where clause
`Table::where('number', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')->orWhere('client_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%') `